# Simple Way to Check if the Ruby array is a matrix?

Tags: ruby

I am working on a project that involves checking if the input is a  n-dimensional matrix(and find its dimensions) and raise error if not.  For example

```
arr = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]] ]
```

is a matrix of dimensions [3 2 2]. What would be the simplest generic way to do that ?

Comment: Ohh I am sorry. I just meant a matrix with no missing elements.

Comment: What's a matrix with missing elements look like?

Comment: Okay I meant something like  a = [[1,2], [3]]  is not really a matrix. because its not 2*2 shape or 2*1 shape so in that case I must raise an error. However if it were a=[[1,2],[3,4]] then it would be a matrix.

Comment: @ArafatK Do you know the dimensions before testing the array?

Comment: Interesting, non-trivial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive solution, but not pretty easy to understand.

```
arr1 = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]]
arr2 = [[[1, 2], [4]], [6, [7, 8]]]

def dimensions(m)
  if m.any? { |e| e.is_a?(Array) }
    d = m.group_by { |e| e.is_a?(Array) && dimensions(e) }.keys
    [m.size] + d.first if d.size == 1 && d.first
  else
    [m.size]
  end
end

dimensions(arr1)  #=> [3, 2, 2]
dimensions(arr2)  #=> nil
```

**Explaination**

The algorithm checks first for nested arrays, `m.any? { |e| e.is_a?(Array) }`.
If there aren't nested arrays then you have just one dimension and it returns the size of the given array via `[m.size]` within the `else` block.

```
dimensions([1,2,3])  #=> [3]
```

If there is at least one nested array then you have to ensure that all elements are arrays and the arrays have the same dimensions. This check is done via `d = m.group_by { |e| e.is_a?(Array) && dimensions(e) }.keys` which groups all elements by its dimensions.

```
[[5, 6], [7, 8]].group_by { |e| ... }.keys
#=> [[2]], all nested array dimensions are equal [2]
[[1, 2], [4]].group_by { |e| ... }.keys
#=> [[1], [2]], different dimensions
[6, [7, 8]].group_by { |e| ... }.keys
#=> [false, [2]], an element isn't an array
```

The algorithm takes only the valid results of the `group_by` with `if d.size == 1 && d.first` and adds the dimensions of the nested arrays to the result via `[m.size] + d.first`.
If there are more than one key element or only `nil` which means all nested arrays are invalid then it returns `nil` implicitly.

That's all.

Comment: _"not pretty easy to understand"_ – that's usually an indicator for some explanation ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the hint. I'll add some explaination.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is a wonderful answer and Exactly what I was looking for,thanks a lot. And the explanation is more than sufficient.

Comment: Very nice answer. I confirmed your code performs correctly against all the example values of `arr` in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby actually has a [Matrix class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html), maybe use that?

```
Matrix[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]]]
#=> Matrix[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]]
Matrix[[1,2], [3]]
# ExceptionForMatrix::ErrDimensionMismatch: row size differs (1 should be 2)
```

Comment: It seems not working for more than 2 dimensions. Try ´Matrix[[[1,2],[4]], [[6],[7,8]]]´.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this seems very easy to do. I was really looking for n-Dimensional matrices as input. Something like t = [[[2], [4], [6]], [[8], [10], [12]], [[14], [16], [18]]]

Answer (score 2):

## Look for patterns in your data

If you look at your example of

```
[[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]]]
```

and dimension `[3, 2, 2]` you can read the dimension element-by-element in the following way:

1. An array of 3 items and each of the items is ...
2. an array of 2 items and each of the subitems is ...
3. an array of 2 items.

This suggest that a dimension can be computed by calling `Array#size` on each level of depth.

## Compute the dimension

The method above can be implemented as:

```rb
def unchecked_matrix_dimension(matrix)
  dimension = []
  while matrix.is_a?(Array)
    dimension << matrix.size
    matrix = matrix[0]
  end
  dimension
end
```

This code looks at elements in the first position only so `[[1], []]` is reported as having dimension of `[2, 1]` but it's not a valid matrix at all.

## Wishful coding

Assume for a moment that we have a function `matrix_dimension?(matrix, dimension)` that returns `true` if `matrix` is of the specified `dimension` and `false` otherwise. We can use it to detect invalid matrices like this:

```rb
def matrix_dimension(matrix)
  dimension = unchecked_matrix_dimension(matrix)
  if matrix_dimension?(matrix, dimension)
    dimension
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

It turns out that writing `matrix_dimension?` is easy!

## Wishes come true

We can define `matrix_dimension?` in a recursive fashion:

1. If `dimension == []` then we expect a scalar value.
2. If `dimension == [d_1]` then we expect an array of `d_1` submatrices of dimension `[]` (i.e. scalars).
3. If `dimension == [d_1, d_2]` then we expect an array of `d_1` submatrices of dimension `[d_2]` (i.e. arrays of `d_2` scalars).

In general, if `dimension == [d_1, ..., d_n]` then we expect an array of `d_1` elements and each of these elements should be of dimension `[d_2, ..., d_n`. In Ruby:

```rb
def matrix_dimension?(matrix, dimension)
  if dimension == []
    !matrix.is_a?(Array)
  else
    matrix.size == dimension[0] &&
      matrix.all? { |submatrix| matrix_dimension?(submatrix, dimension[1..-1]) }
  end
end
```

With this definition of `matrix_dimension?` our `matrix_dimension` function will return the dimension, if the argument is a valid n-dimension matrix, or `nil` otherwise.

## Complete code

```rb
def unchecked_matrix_dimension(matrix)
  dimension = []
  while matrix.is_a?(Array)
    dimension << matrix.size
    matrix = matrix[0]
  end
  dimension
end

def matrix_dimension(matrix)
  dimension = unchecked_matrix_dimension(matrix)
  if matrix_dimension?(matrix, dimension)
    dimension
  else
    nil
  end
end

def matrix_dimension?(matrix, dimension)
  if dimension == []
    !matrix.is_a?(Array)
  else
    matrix.size == dimension[0] &&
      matrix.all? { |submatrix| matrix_dimension?(submatrix, dimension[1..-1]) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer! I confirmed your code performs correctly against the last two example values of `arr` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without use of `Matrix` class:

```
input = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]] ]
m3 = input.map { |a| a.map(&:size) }
m2 = input.map(&:size)
m1 = input.size

checker = ->(e, memo) { raise unless e == memo; e }

[ m1, m2.reduce(&checker), m3.reduce(&checker).reduce(&checker) ]
#⇒ [3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Did you just call `raise` without an argument?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, I did. Why?

Comment: Programmers love getting a message-less `RuntimeError` where they expected `false`. Getting an array where they expected `true` is less bad.

Comment: @JanDvorak I do never provide a production-ready solution; I have an idea shown. Programmers love different things, adopting code to their needs is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was really looking for n-Dimensional matrices as input.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this using recursion. If the array represents an n-dimensional matrix, an array of dimensions is returned; else `false` is returned.

**Code**

```
def ndim_matrix(arr)
  return false if arr.map(&:size).uniq != [arr.first.size]
  arrays, literals = arr.partition { |e| e.is_a? Array }
  return [arr.size] if arrays.empty?
  return false unless literals.empty?
  res = arr.map { |e| ndim_matrix(e) }.uniq
  return false if res.size > 1 or res == [false]
  [arr.size, *res.first]
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [1,2]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> [2]

arr = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> [2,3]

arr = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6,7] ]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> false

arr = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]] ]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> [3,2,2]

arr = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,10]] ]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> false

arr = [ [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6,7],[7,8]], [[9,10],[11,12]] ]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> false

arr = [ [[[1,2,3],[2,1,3]],[[3,4,5],[4,3,2]]],
        [[[5,6,7],[6,5,7]],[[7,8,9],[8,7,6]]],
        [[[9,10,11],[10,9,8]],[[11,12,13],[12,11,10]]] ]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> [3, 2, 2, 3]

arr = [ [[[1,2,3],[2,1,3]],[[3,4],[4,3]]],
        [[[5,6,7],[6,5,7]],[[7,8,9],[8,7,6]]],
        [[[9,10,11],[10,9,8]],[[11,12,13],[12,11,10]]] ]
ndim_matrix(arr)
  #=> false
```